# Writing a text file to a table using VBScript

Tags: sql, vbscript, batch-file, sql-server-2008-r2

I have input line like-

```
001-407600 12/26/2011 04:25:43.250 12/26/2011 04:25:43.156
001-338000 12/26/2011 04:22:49.250 12/26/2011 04:22:49.156
001-51600 12/26/2011 04:10:53.234 12/26/2011 04:10:53.140
001-351900 12/26/2011 04:23:24.000 12/26/2011 04:23:23.906
```

and i want to write this data into table `DATATABLE` with column name `jobid` `date1` `time1` `date2` `time2` respectively by using VB Script

Please suggest me how can i do this.

Comment: would [this](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_read-write-binary-files/) be of help?

Comment: Why in a VBScript file? Why not take advantage of [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)?

Comment: Or even simpler, [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.105).aspx)? "Line by line" is how they did it in the 70s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure of the formatting of the text file, so you may have to play with `FIELDTERMINATOR` and `ROWTERMINATOR`, but this approach will be much easier and more efficient than trying to do this line by line.

```
set conn = createobject("ADODB.Connection")

connstr = "Provider=SQLNCLI;Data Source=server\instance;User ID=username;" & _
          "Password=password;Initial Catalog=database_name;"

conn.open connstr

filepath = "c:\wherever\whatever.txt"

sql = "BULK INSERT dbo.DATATABLE FROM '" & filepath & "'" & _
      " WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n', FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ');"

conn.execute sql,,129

conn.close : set conn = nothing
```